# How can I Register a OAuth 2.0 app into Azure AD?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-app-registration

I want to register a OAuth 2.0 app into Azure AD. Should i use App registration option or Enterprise Apps blade? I need step wise procedure as I cant find full procedure in MS docs. My client is asking for below values from  me some of which I can give.

Test Environment of app

Client ID   : can give
Client Secret   : can give
Client secret expiration date (if applicable)
Scope (if applicable)
Authorization URL
Authorization Request payload and format
Token URL
Token request payload and format
User info URL (if applicable)
User info Request payload and format (if applicable)
Sample token

Also how to do Role and Locational mapping for my tenant users for the Oauth app in app registrations?

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your app (app registration).
Once you then consent to the app, its going to be installed under enterprise application.

Creating and assigning roles: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-apps

You define the contract in the app (app registrations) and assign the roles to users/groups on the enterprise applications (instance of the app registration if you like).

For locational mapping, you need to configure the custom claims (under 'Token Configuration'), and make sure you add the claim you need. Theres a ctry and a tenant_ctry.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/905638/optional-claim-tenany-ctry-in-aad-token

Besides, look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal

Comment: Hi can we map user location in custom claims other than country.